# Submitting a paper that contains the researcher name to a conference that employs double blind reviewing

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, conference

Me and my co-researchers are submitting a paper regarding speech recognition to a conference that is held by the university where we study. In this study, we, strictly for the purpose of trolling, included our co-researchers name into the dictionary for speech recognition. Curiously, the performance of the speech recognition at recognizing the researcher's name has generated interesting insight for analysis. The analysis works by breaking down the phonetic of the researcher's name. The usage of the researcher's name is crucial since the researcher's name provides the best example.

Unfortunately, the conference that we're submitting to employs a double-blind peer reviewing system and my researcher whose name we used is widely known in the university for his achievements and trolling so it's very likely the reviewer knows him.

Is there anything I can do to mitigate this besides submitting to a different conference?

Comment: can you not find a single other word that generates the same effect?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to see how it would be obvious to a reviewer that the researcher whose name is used is also an author. In this case there should be no issue about reviewing.

But, you could also inform the conference chair and ask for advice there.

In some similar cases it might be possible to obfuscate the name for review purposes, but your description indicates that isn't possible here. But, you might need to change a few phrases if they make the relationship explicit. And note, also, that the final version is normally a bit different from the reviewed version. Reviewers themselves often suggest changes.